# How to retrieve facebook user's friends albums information with facebook php sdk

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Im kind of new in facebook development, so be patient with me :)
I'm creating an app that manage the photo albums user. One of the features i'm developing needs to access the friends photos. I mean, the photos that my app user can see of his friends. How can retrieve thats albums and photos information? I have user_photos and friends_photos permission.
Any sugestion?

Thanks in advance!!

Sorry for my lame english. Is not my native language.

Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make an API call, for this you can use Facebook Graph API.
Look at the following API for albums

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/

This is for generic purpose, however you need to first pull all the friends from here

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/FriendList/

To fetch the albums of a friend you also need to set permissions

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

check:friends_photos

You can simply fetch the album like this

https://graph.facebook.com/{userId}/albums?accessToken=something

PS. you need to pull albums of friends one by one.

Comment: I have friend_photos permissions and retrieve the friend list with the api. How can I use the api to get the albums that user can see from his friends? Can you give me some code line example to do this? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: for instance you get the user id of  friend = 123456 so it will be like that https://graph.facebook.com/123456/albums?accessToken=something

Comment: use Graph API Explorer http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Falbums

Comment: Yes, I tried that and give me a blank array :/
I will keep searching. I think I have to do something from the user that use my app. That example is like trying to get the albums directly from another user that not necessary use my app, so dont get any results. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You may doesn't have rights to see, try with some test ids if you have!

Answer (score 0):

**References to get you started**

Start with the Graph API:
developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Read up on a few more things:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Use Graph explorer to test things out:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

**Your fist app**

Now in order to do anything on facebook you need to create an application. You will get an app token when you do this. Something like: *288229791195831*

Your users need to Like your application in order to use it. Then you can use it to post photos, wall messages etc.

This is the URL your application could use to log in a user:

> https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=288229791195831&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&type=user_agent&display=popup&scope=publish_stream,user_photos,read_stream,email

Replace your *client_id* with the app id you get from facebook. *Scope* shows the permissions this app is requesting.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for take your time to answer me. Im new but not so much, hehe. The situation is like this. When I try a /$iduser/albums, I get all the $iduser(the person using the app) albums information. I can retrieve the ids of that user friends and try /$idsomefriend/albums and I get blank. Have user_photos and friends_photo permission. Any Idea?

Comment: @zorbakan I think the albums are private and "nobody" can access private albums

Comment: For test i use my facebook user. From my facebook user i can see some albums. I want my app see what the user that use the app see. At first tried /$userid/friends/$friendid/albums but is not working. What i have to do to get my user scope and see what he see? Thanks!

Comment: @zorbakan test your code if you can retrieve the albums here http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/