# What Facebook permissions are required to view photos that your friends are tagged in?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

It seems that the answer is the `friends_photos` permission, see these answers

- [How to retrieve facebook user's friends albums information with facebook php sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019156/how-to-retrieve-facebook-users-friends-albums-information-with-facebook-php-sdk)
- [Facebook Graph API: Permissions to Friends Photos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047785/facebook-graph-api-permissions-to-friends-photos)

However, there is no reference to it in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0).  I fear it may have been removed?  Can anyone confirm it is still possible to get friends photos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you created the app after 4/30/2014 you have only access to v2.0 of the API and you can not access any friends data

Comment: Thank you very much for for this.  Do you have a link to the docs that state this?  My App was created before 2014, do you know if there is a depreciation plan?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading/ you have until 4/30/2015. So a little less than one year.

Answer (score 2):

There is limited access to friend's timeline, photos and videos in v2 API.

UserA can see the timeline, photos and videos of UserB if and only if,

- They are friends
- Both granted `user_friends` permission to your application and
- UserB also grants the `user_posts`, `user_photos` and `user_videos` permissions to your application.

The following steps can be used to test the same in the graph API explorer.

1. using access token of UserA call `me/friends`
2. get id of UserB from response
3. call `[UserB-id]/albums`
4. get album id
5. call `[album-id]/photos`